# Where Do I Get job listing from http://developer.dol.gov?

Tags: labor

Can any one help me to integrate http://developer.dol.gov api for getting listing of jobs?

Comment: Are you looking for a listing of job titles?

Comment: want to  use api for getting list of job title with all information like description salaty education job url etc.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer, but is too long for a comment.

If you just want to dl the data, searching http://data.gov (not dol.gov) for "job titles" or "job title salary" (both without quotes) may be helpful. Some useful links:

- https://www.data.gov/search-results?group=site&q=job%20titles%20salary
- https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/title-and-salary-listing
- https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/salary-ranges-by-job-classification-9be65
- https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?q=job+titles&sort=score+desc%2C+name+asc&as_sfid=AAAAAAVsDA68piSSjKE_mV3bS3qEET26TKEz39NJuA6QcxnEx9pSpYeG2afZskUadFGpvLj_ErPri-sbXpPin14dHVUmIbT9KUSa32HCKJUS24H7DIgNVVlYGC71K_7CdCOqF-w%3D&as_fid=8bf9593a9f5f216187d5c6329386d0e59aab35c9&ext_location=&ext_bbox=&ext_prev_extent=-142.03125%2C8.754794702435618%2C-59.0625%2C61.77312286453146

Note that some of these are state or city specific, so be sure to read the data description before use.